# この世に生まれてきてしまった - How does this translate to "born into the world"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, anime

The full phrase is:

> ですが私は死にたくありません (but I don't want to die)
>
> この世に生まれてきてしまったからです (because I was born into this world)

I think I understand the vocabulary break down. I just don't understand how this all grammatically connects to the English translated sentence.

この世に - to this world

生まれて - born, but with progressive te? Or is the te just connecting?

きて - I came, progressive te? Connecting te?

しまった - I did, but I didn't mean to do it? Could this have been しました?

からです - because.

I guess I can roughly translate it in reverse as "because I did come born to this world". But I feel I'm missing some nuances in the grammar. Can anyone explain to me what are the tes and the shimata doing?

Btw, this is a line from Attack on Titan. But I don't believe it's a spoiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've broken down everything perfectly. 生まれてきて is the combination of 生まれる＋てくる in the Te-form. This is a grammar point that is [explained in more depth here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/helping-verbs/). Here, てくる essentially adds the nuance that someone is "born **into** (this world)" rather than just "born in (this world)".

You are correct that this [～てしまう](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/utilization-of-the-te-form/#1) means something accidental and often undesirable. Being born into this world is not something intentional, and I assume being born in a world full of huge human eating babies is not something desirable as well. adding ～てしまう gives that nuance here. So 生まれてくる＋てしまう gives you 生まれてき**てしまう**→born into (this world) **unintentionally**.

I think you have a good grasp on the rest of the sentence, so let's put them together.

> この世に 
> In this world

> この世に生まれてきてしまう 
> Born into this world (unintentionally)

> この世に生まれてきてしまったからです 
> Because I was born into this world (unintentionally and perhaps undesirably).

Comment: Did you mean 来る when you said "てくる"? As in the "te" is connecting "born" with "come" to create "born and come" ?